# Select Items using checkbox and Multiple Submit options

Tags: buttons, checkboxes

A web page defines a few search criterion. When user submits the search criterion, the search results are rendered on the page. These results are email addresses to which the user might want to send an email. This is an email marketing tool. After the first page of results are rendered, the user needs to have the option to:

1. Send email to every email address which was returned as part of search.
2. Use checkboxes to send email to a subset of results.

So there are 2 submit button (Send Email button) options for the user. 
We started looking into the idea of actually having 2 Send Email buttons on the page. I am looking for better approaches usability and design wise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide an additional checkbox to select **all** results. This way you'll only need one button. Furthermore the *Select All* checkbox is a control used by many websites (e.g. GMail, GWT, etc.)

I strongly recommend to use only one button, as the action (*send e-mail*) remains the same, it's only the input that changes.

Comment: What is the visual cue for the user when he has used the Select All checkbox? The site renders 1 page of results at a time, so using the Select All checkbox will visually mark all the items on the current page as selected, which has the same visual effect as Selecting All Items on Page. Can this be improved upon?

Comment: IMHO the important thing is to keep the *selecting* and *sending* apart. If the user really wants to send the e-mail to *all* search results, then you should give them a way to display and select all search results on one page. Then selecting them with one click and then send them by hitting the button. Including results the user cannot see should be avoided.